# How can a blob image be uploaded from REST console( such as Google chrome's POSTMAN ) to azure blob storage?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Having sasquerystring and image url from backend how can a image upload be done from REST console

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you have a SAS Query String and the URL of the image you want to upload. Is this correct? Or do you want to upload a local file?

Comment: yeah i have a sasquerystring and image url. Now i just need to check whether i can upload the image file. And  I need to check it from Rest Console as i mentioned .

Comment: Can this document help you? https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests

Comment: One more clarification question: The URL of the image is a publicly accessible URL outside of Azure. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes gaurav, thats correct

Comment: Dag, thanks for the link  but i know how to use postman for other cases. However in the case with azure blob storage i could not configure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using just a `Shared Access Signature` on the target container/blob (where you want the image to be copied), as of today it is not possible to copy an image by using image URL.

What you have to do is create an authorization signature (following the procedure listed [`here`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179428.aspx)) and then use [`Copy Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd894037.aspx) REST API functionality. Once you properly create authorization header, then you will be able to copy the image using a URL provided the image URL is publicly accessible.

Other alternative would be to download the image from that URL on your local computer and then you will be able to upload the image to blob container using [`Put Blob`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179451.aspx) REST API using POSTMAN.